# Extending Leaflet Routing Machine to work with Here Maps

Tags: leaflet, mapbox, here-api, leaflet-routing-machine

[Leaflet Routing Machine](https://github.com/perliedman/leaflet-routing-machine) provides an easy way to integrate directions capabilities in Leaflet. Out of the box it used to work with MapBox but it is a while since it has been updated and I find thaat it does not quite work anymore.  In any case I want to use Leaflet + LRM with my chosen provider - HERE maps.  The HERE Maps directions URL bears the form

```
https://route.ls.hereapi.com/routing/7.2/calculateroute.json?apiKey=<API_KEY>&waypoint0=geo!lat0,lng0
```

9&waypoint1=geo!lat1,lng1&mode=fastest;car;traffic:disabled

How can I modify Leaflet Routing machine to access and then use the results provided by the Here Directions API?

Answer (score 1):

There is a plugin for here's routing API: https://github.com/Daredzik/lrm-Here

Haven't used it myself, but looks good.

Comment: Thank you,  In the mean time I had simply modified the original LRM code myself - that Here LRM plugin is rather old.  b.t.w - you may not have noticed this: `leaflet-routing-machine.js` is completely missing in the current Github archive.  Even your examples refer to  `../dist/leaflet-routing-machine.js` and do not work

Comment: @DroidOS `dist` files are not included in the repo, you have to build the project to create them. It's common practice for almost any JS project.